# Assembly, global variable

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

I have the following source code:

```
const ClassTwo g_classTwo;

void ClassOne::first()
{
    g_classTwo.doSomething(1);
}

void ClassOne::second()
{
    g_classTwo.doSomething(2);
}
```

Which produces the following objdump:

```
void ClassOne::first()
{
 1089c50:   e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
 1089c54:   e92dd800    push    {fp, ip, lr, pc}
 1089c58:   e24cb004    sub fp, ip, #4
 1089c5c:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
 1089c60:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
    g_classTwo.doSomething(1);
 1089c64:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 1089c80 <ClassOne::first()+0x30>
 1089c68:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
 1089c6c:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
 1089c70:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1
 1089c74:   ebffffe2    bl  1089c04 <ClassTwo::doSomething(int) const>
}
 1089c78:   e24bd00c    sub sp, fp, #12
 1089c7c:   e89da800    ldm sp, {fp, sp, pc}
 1089c80:   060cd35c    .word   0x060cd35c

01089c84 <ClassOne::second()>:

void ClassOne::second()
{
 1089c84:   e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
 1089c88:   e92dd800    push    {fp, ip, lr, pc}
 1089c8c:   e24cb004    sub fp, ip, #4
 1089c90:   e24dd008    sub sp, sp, #8
 1089c94:   e50b0010    str r0, [fp, #-16]
    g_classTwo.doSomething(2);
 1089c98:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 1089cb4 <ClassOne::second()+0x30>
 1089c9c:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
 1089ca0:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
 1089ca4:   e3a01002    mov r1, #2
 1089ca8:   ebffffd5    bl  1089c04 <ClassTwo::doSomething(int) const>
}
 1089cac:   e24bd00c    sub sp, fp, #12
 1089cb0:   e89da800    ldm sp, {fp, sp, pc}
 1089cb4:   060cd328    .word   0x060cd328
```

Both methods are loading the address of `g_classTwo` with a pc relative offset: `ldr r3, [pc, #20]`, which translates to `0x060cd35c` and `0x060cd328` for the first and second method respectively.

Why are the addresses different even though they are both addressing the same global variable?

How do those addresses relate to the nm output for the same symbol: `07156fcc b g_classTwo`?

Comment: Just to be clear, the two functions are loading different addresses from different literal pools.  ("translates to" isn't the most clear description.  At first I thought you were just saying that there were two literal pools with two copies of the same pointer.)

Comment: Look at what it does with each offset immediately after loading them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ClassOne::first()` you have:

```
1089c64:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 1089c80 <ClassOne::first()+0x30>
1089c68:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
1089c6c:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
...
1089c80:   060cd35c    .word   0x060cd35c
```

In `ClassOne::second()` you have:

```
1089c98:   e59f3014    ldr r3, [pc, #20]   ; 1089cb4 <ClassOne::second()+0x30>
1089c9c:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
1089ca0:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
...
1089cb4:   060cd328    .word   0x060cd328
```

In both, `r0` is the `this` pointer (`g_classTwo`). As you can see, after loading an address from the literal pool into `r3` it is summed to `pc` to get `r0`.

In `ClassOne::first()`, you get `r0 = pc + r3 = 0x01089c70 + 0x060cd35c = 0x07156fcc`.

In `ClassOne::second()`, you get `r0 = pc + r3 = 0x01089ca4 + 0x060cd328 = 0x07156fcc`.

So for both the `this` pointer is `0x07156fcc`, which is the address of `g_classTwo`.

Comment: You've got the PC values wrong - they would be 0x1089c70 and 0x1089ca4 respectively. Which also correlates with address of `g_classTwo` already being known to be 0x07156fcc.

Comment: @Notlikethat Fixed. I got confused by `LDR` using `PC-4`, why is that?

Comment: That immediate is _decimal_ 20, i.e. 0x14.

Comment: @Notlikethat Excuse me while I go into a corner with a cup of coffee and cry.